# Select records which does not return from inner join

Tags: sql-server

I am using the following query to inner join my two tables.

```
select a.*
from AllUK a
join AllCompanies b
on replace(a.Address1 + a.Postcode,' ','') = replace(b.street + b.Postcode,' ','')
```

I want to return the rest of the records in the AllUK table, which is not returned by the inner join.

Answer (score 1):

try this......

```
select a.*
from AllUK a
left join AllCompanies b
on replace(a.Address1 + a.Postcode,' ','') = replace(b.street + b.Postcode,' ','')
where replace(b.street + b.Postcode,' ','') is null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much the definition of the [EXCEPT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) action:

```
select a.*
from AllUK a

EXCEPT 

select a.*
from AllUK a
join AllCompanies b
on replace(a.Address1 + a.Postcode,' ','') = replace(b.street + b.Postcode,' ','')
```

Comment: You beat me to it. EXCEPT is exactly what I was going to post.

Answer (score 0):

I like to stick to `IN` and `NOT IN` commands to make it simple to read.

```
Select a.*
from AllUk a
where a.ID not in (
select a.id
from AllUK a
join AllCompanies b
on replace(a.Address1 + a.Postcode,' ','') = replace(b.street + b.Postcode,' ',''))
```